# What is the correct way to assign a value to a DateTime Variable that is in a C# List?

Tags: c#, list, blazor

When I run my web app that  am building using Blazor on DotNet 5, The Date column in my html table keeps giving me the default value.
Here is the initialization of the List:

```
        var groupLoans = new List<Loan>();
        groupLoans.Add(new Loan { LoanId = 1000, LoanAmount = 5000, GroupId = 001, DateDisbursed = new DateTime(14 / 14 / 2021), PaybackDate = new DateTime(01 / 09 / 2022) });
        groupLoans.Add(new Loan { LoanId = 2000, LoanAmount = 7000, GroupId = 003, DateDisbursed = new DateTime(07 / 09 / 2021), PaybackDate = new DateTime(01 / 09 / 2022) });
        groupLoans.Add(new Loan { LoanId = 1000, LoanAmount = 5000, GroupId = 002, DateDisbursed = new DateTime(07 / 09 / 2021), PaybackDate = new DateTime(01 / 09 / 2022) });
```

Comment: use date in double quotes. let me know if u still face issue.

Comment: It gives me the following error: CS1503: Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'long'.

Comment: The example at this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0 is `DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18);`

Comment: C# doesn't have a date literal, you have to call one of the other DateTime constructors. `(14 / 14 / 2021) == 0` that's a series of divide operations.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the constructor and the possible overloads it has?

Comment: yes, and I have found the correct format: 
SomeDate = new DateTime(yyyy, mm, dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the date initialize format.

```
// YEAR,MONTH,DAY 
DateTime DateDisbursed = new DateTime(2021, 12, 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//assign year, month, day
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2021,12,14);
        Console.WriteLine(dt2);
```

You can format your datetime according to your needs as below:

```
dt2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: SomeDate = new DateTime(yyyy, mm, dd)

I just put something like this in my list.
THANKS!

Comment: you are welcome, Can you accept the answer if that helped you :) ?